# tf-2.0-alpha trouble running distributed keras with ParameterServer strategy

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, distributed, tensorflow2.0

In tf2, I'm trying to train a neural network in distributed way using keras. I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/distribute/keras

The strategy used in this tutorial is MirroredStrategy. But I wanna run the code from multiple machines. Currently in tf2 for distributed keras only Mirrored and Parameter-Server strategies are supported. So I just tried to change the strategy to Parameter-Server (with Mirrored it works fine).

I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error copying tensor to device: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0. /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 unknown device.
```

One more thing kinda irrelevant to this post. In tf2 only MirroredStrategy is supported for custom training loops (without the use of keras or estimator). Does anyone know if it's possible somehow to distribute training throughout multiple machines with custom training loops?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code for the 1st worker. It's the same as the one in the tutorial with the addition of TF_CONFIG and the change of the strategy.
(tensorflow 2.0 alpha)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

import os, json

datasets, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

mnist_train, mnist_test = datasets['train'], datasets['test']

os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
    "cluster": {
        "worker": ["x.y.z.w1:12345", "x.y.z.w2:12345"],
        "ps": ["x.y.z.w3:12345"]
    },
    "task": {"type": "worker", "index": 0}
})

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.ParameterServerStrategy()

print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

# You can also do info.splits.total_num_examples to get the total
# number of examples in the dataset.

num_train_examples = info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_test_examples = info.splits['test'].num_examples

BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 64
BATCH_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

def scale(image, label):
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image /= 255

  return image, label

train_dataset = mnist_train.map(scale).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
eval_dataset = mnist_test.map(scale).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

with strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  ])

  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

# Define the checkpoint directory to store the checkpoints

checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
# Name of the checkpoint files
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

# Function for decaying the learning rate.
# You can define any decay function you need.
def decay(epoch):
  if epoch < 3:
    return 1e-3
  elif epoch >= 3 and epoch < 7:
    return 1e-4
  else:
    return 1e-5

# Callback for printing the LR at the end of each epoch.
class PrintLR(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    print('\nLearning rate for epoch {} is {}'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                      model.optimizer.lr.numpy()))

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs'),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
                                       save_weights_only=True),
    tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(decay),
    PrintLR()
]

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=12, callbacks=callbacks)

model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))

eval_loss, eval_acc = model.evaluate(eval_dataset)

print('Eval loss: {}, Eval Accuracy: {}'.format(eval_loss, eval_acc))
```

Expected output should be something like:

```
Epoch 1/12
    938/Unknown - 11s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2151 - accuracy: 0.9380
Learning rate for epoch 1 is 0.0010000000474974513
938/938 [==============================] - 11s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2151 - accuracy: 0.9380
Epoch 2/12
937/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0678 - accuracy: 0.9801
Learning rate for epoch 2 is 0.0010000000474974513
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0678 - accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 3/12
935/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0473 - accuracy: 0.9865
Learning rate for epoch 3 is 0.0010000000474974513
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0473 - accuracy: 0.9865
Epoch 4/12
931/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0258 - accuracy: 0.9931
Learning rate for epoch 4 is 9.999999747378752e-05
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0258 - accuracy: 0.9931
Epoch 5/12
934/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0229 - accuracy: 0.9944
Learning rate for epoch 5 is 9.999999747378752e-05
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0228 - accuracy: 0.9944
Epoch 6/12
928/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0211 - accuracy: 0.9947
Learning rate for epoch 6 is 9.999999747378752e-05
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0211 - accuracy: 0.9947
Epoch 7/12
928/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0196 - accuracy: 0.9952
Learning rate for epoch 7 is 9.999999747378752e-05
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0195 - accuracy: 0.9952
Epoch 8/12
928/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0169 - accuracy: 0.9961
Learning rate for epoch 8 is 9.999999747378752e-06
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0168 - accuracy: 0.9961
Epoch 9/12
925/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0167 - accuracy: 0.9962
Learning rate for epoch 9 is 9.999999747378752e-06
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0166 - accuracy: 0.9962
Epoch 10/12
935/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0164 - accuracy: 0.9962
Learning rate for epoch 10 is 9.999999747378752e-06
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0164 - accuracy: 0.9962
Epoch 11/12
932/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0163 - accuracy: 0.9963
Learning rate for epoch 11 is 9.999999747378752e-06
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0162 - accuracy: 0.9963
Epoch 12/12
933/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0161 - accuracy: 0.9963
Learning rate for epoch 12 is 9.999999747378752e-06
938/938 [==============================] - 7s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0160 - accuracy: 0.9964
```

And what I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_dist.py", line 58, in <module>
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self._device_scope.__exit__(exception_type, exception_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 603, in device
    yield
  File "keras_dist.py", line 53, in <module>
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 169, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 662, in __call__
    self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, previous_mask)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 391, in call_context
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 653, in __call__
    self._set_inputs(inputs, outputs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 319, in inner_cm
    self._graph_key = old_graph_key
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5486, in get_controller
    yield g
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5293, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5486, in get_controller
    yield g
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 485, in _mode
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5486, in get_controller
    yield g
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 314, in inner_cm
    yield g
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 653, in __call__
    self._set_inputs(inputs, outputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6361, in __exit__
    self._name_scope.__exit__(type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4183, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 594, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1713, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 165, in build
    dtype=self.dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 377, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 622, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 152, in make_variable
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 212, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 175, in _variable_v1_call
    aggregation=aggregation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 58, in getter
    return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 823, in creator_with_resource_vars
    return self._create_variable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy.py", line 361, in _create_variable
    return var_creator(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4269, in _colocate_with_for_gradient
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4333, in colocate_with
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4269, in _colocate_with_for_gradient
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy.py", line 361, in _create_variable
    return var_creator(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4411, in device
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/parameter_server_strategy.py", line 361, in _create_variable
    return var_creator(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 154, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2492, in default_variable_creator
    import_scope=import_scope, distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 216, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 422, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 619, in _init_from_args
    ops.add_to_collections(ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5622, in init_scope
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 485, in _mode
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5622, in init_scope
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/tape.py", line 122, in stop_recording
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5622, in init_scope
    yield
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 551, in _init_from_args
    graph_mode=self._in_graph_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4775, in _attr_scope
    yield  # The code within the context runs here.
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 545, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 134, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 434, in __call__
    return self._random_generator.random_uniform(shape, -limit, limit, dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py", line 797, in random_uniform
    shape=shape, minval=minval, maxval=maxval, dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 240, in random_uniform
    minval = ops.convert_to_tensor(minval, dtype=dtype, name="min")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1108, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1186, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 304, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 245, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 253, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 110, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    t = ops.EagerTensor(value, handle, device, dtype)
RuntimeError: Error copying tensor to device: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0. /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 unknown device.
```

Comment: I'm also interested in what the support story for `ParameterServerStrategy` will be going forward